# Response of an Returning Promise is not working: undefined Variable

Tags: node.js, api, async-await, promise

Hi I am wondering that my response of a Promise is not working. I always get "undefined" Variable if want to get access in the .then function.

Here´s my example:

```
class BookingRoute extends BasicRoute{
  constructor(schemaModel) {
    super();
      Schema = schemaModel;
    }

 async post(req, res){      // Example for Override
  super.post(Schema, req, res, StoredBookings)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(422).send("Error while router.get api/products");
  });
}

class BasicRoute {
         async post(Schema, req, res, storedItems) {
         console.log("post " + Schema.modelName);
         (req.body != null ? null : res.status(422).send("Error while router.get api/xxx"));
         let schema = new Schema(req.body);
         await schema
           .save()
           .then((result)=> {
              storedItems.push(result);
              return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                console.log("Datay from Array...");
                console.log(storedItems);
                resolve(storedItems);
              })
           })
            .catch(error =>{
              return new Error("Wrong Parameter router.get api/xxx/parameters");
            })
       }
}
```

I am wondering, because the output of the stored Items is working fine.
But the output of the result is always "undefined".

I have following console output:

```
post Bookings
Datay from Array...
[
  {
    Products: [ 1000, 2000 ],
    StartDate: '31.05.2021',
    EndDate: '31.05.2021',
    StartTime: 10,
    EndTime: 5,
    TotalPrice: 4,
    OrderNumber: 10,
    __v: 0
  }
]
undefined
```

Does somebody has any idea please?
Thank you

Comment: You forgot to return promise from `BasicRoute.post`. Obviously should be `return await schema.save().then(...).catch(...)`

Comment: Thank you, it works.

But i thought if i return:

return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                resolve(storedItems);
              })

this should be a promise, that i can use in my main class. 
thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, any async function always implicitly returns promise.

Comment: Write in console something like `(async function () { return 123; })()` and you will see that this function will return resolved promise: `Promise {<fulfilled>: 123}`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript or TypeScript, classes don't expected a function as a member.

I'm using VS Code as my code editor, and the terminal shows me an error:
`Unexpected token. a constructor method accessor or property was expected`.
This error points to your class `class BasicRoute`

So, the problem is `async post()`.

You need to bind to a method instead.

Hope you can think in a solution. If not, reply me to help you.